# branch.io onInitFinished is called with null object

Tags: android, branch.io

I have the following code snippet in my app. When onInitiFinished is called, on Samsung Galaxy 6, running 6.0.1, the BranchUniversalObject is passed as null. On Nexus 5, running 6.0.1, and Samsung Galaxy 5, running 5.0, the BranchUniversalObject is non-null and contains all of the info embedded in the link.

On all 3 devices, when clicking on the link, the browser starts up and then my app is started (as expected).

```
private void setupBranch() {
Branch branch = Branch.getInstance();
boolean branchInitOk = branch.initSession(new Branch.BranchUniversalReferralInitListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInitFinished(BranchUniversalObject branchUniversalObject, LinkProperties linkProperties, BranchError error) {
        if (error == null && branchUniversalObject != null) {
            String cannonicalIdentifier = branchUniversalObject.getCanonicalIdentifier();
            ...
        }
    }
});
```

}

What can I look at to debug this problem?

Comment: In which app on each device are you opening the link?

Comment: On Galaxy6 I tried using the default messenger app and Viper. Neither one works. On the Nexus device, I tried using Hangout and Viper, both work. I don't think the issue is with the app that opens the link, as the entire branch deep linking flow seems to work up to the point of calling onNewIntent() of the Activity responsible for handling this. It's the onInitFinished() that is never called with the non-null BranchUniversalObject on the Galaxy6 device.

Comment: I cannot think of any reason why this would be broken on a specific device, and I definitely haven't heard of issues with the Galaxy 6 in the past. Perhaps you could submit a ticket to the [Branch Integrations team](https://support.branch.io/support/tickets/new) so they can debug more closely?